# Most secure way to have IPtables auto-loaded using Debian / Linux

Tags: linux, networking, debian, firewall, iptables

I'd like to know the safest way to load iptables using Debian. Of course, I can use a script that uses iptables-restore :

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/firewall.conf
```

but :
1) where is the safest place to have it loaded ? /etc/network/if-up.d ?
I'm concerned about the script being loaded early enough at boot time, and reliably enough when plugging/unplugging interfaces ...

2) is this script method using iptables-restore the most secure way ?

3) additionnally, how much does the answer validity stretch to other Linux distros ( Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS ) ?

Thanks ^^

Comment: Write your rules in `/etc/network/if-up.d/rules.sh` by doing `sudo iptables-save > /etc/network/if-up.d/rules.sh` and then add `/etc/network/if-up.d/rules.sh` to `/etc/rc.local` before the line `exit 0`

Comment: Did you already look at this resource: http://www.debian-administration.org/article/615/Restoring_iptables_Automatically_On_Boot ? Using if-pre-up.d seems to address your concern that iptables is loaded *before* the interface is up.

Comment: OK, so /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ seems like a good place to locate the script. But is it really 'packet-proof' ( I mean, no small time-lapse while a packet might sneak in while iptables is resetting ? ( I try to make it packet-proof ) ?

Comment: also, using if-pre-up.d/ would have the script flush the iptables each time a network-interfaces is down-ed or up-ed. This is inconvenient for fail2ban as an example. Wouldn't a strategically placed init.d script with custom update-rc.d settings be a more definitive solution ? But how to know when to have it started exactly ? ( ie what update-rc.d runlevel values and priorities use ), and have dependencies checked ?

Comment: Nehal J. Wani : why do you add /etc/network/if-up.d/rules.sh to /etc/rc.local ? so to make sure it's executed anyway ?

Answer (score 1):

Debian includes a ready package to do this: [iptables-persistent](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=iptables-persistent). I have used that and it works well on Debian and Ubuntu. Without performing much of a security analysis, I find it a good practice to use ready made solutions instead of rolling your own.

```
apt-get install iptables-persistent
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```